# How to call an async function inherited from parent class?

Tags: typescript, server, async-await, es6-promise

This is my parent class, it connects to the DB using the function startServer().

```
export class BaseServer {
  constructor(port: number, databaseURL: string) {
    config.port = port;
    config.databaseURL = databaseURL;
   }

  async startServer() {
     const app = express();
     const server: express.Application = await require('./loaders').default({ expressApp: app });

      server.listen(config.port, () => {
        Logger.info(`
          ################################################
          ️  Server listening on port: ${config.port} ️
          ################################################
    `    );
      }).on('error', err => {
        Logger.error(err);
        process.exit(1);
      });
  }
}
// calling server
// const obj = new BaseServer(config.port, config.databaseURL);
// obj.startServer();
```

In another file I import the BaseServer and extend it like this.

```
const obj = new BaseServer(4000, 'mongodb+srv://alex:123@cluster0.iskpf.mongodb.net/passandgoTest?retryWrites=true&w=majority');
obj.startServer();
```

Its giving no errors but a db should have been made on mongo atlas with the name of 'passandgoTest'.

Simply calling baseServer instance in the parent file does create the db.

I am new to typescript and all. Please give me some right direction to move forward.

Comment: Did you read the error message?

Comment: yes its says to put a try/catch. I put a try/catch inside the async function also around where obj was called but still same eror.

Comment: it is telling you that it can only have one instance of `BaseServer`

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar i removed the instance of baseServer from the parent class. Now it is giving no errors but its also not making a db on mongo atlas.